# React Native: TouchableHighLight onPress not working in renderHeader method of ListView

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

The way I did it is as follows, when press the header, opacity does change, yet nothing is logged in chrome debugger console.

```
  onHeaderPressed() {
    console.log('onHeaderPresseded is called');
  }

  renderHeader() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.header}
        onPress={this.onHeaderPress}
        activeOpacity={0.6}
        underlayColor={'blue'}>
        <View>
          <Text>
            Click here
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <ListView 
        style={styles.container}
        renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(item) => this.renderListItem(item)}
        />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please try it with removing the `<View>` wrapper around `<Text>` inside `TouchableOpacity` in the `renderHeader` method? It can be a solution for you at this moment.

Comment: Perhaps, You need to `bind` your function. Something like `onPress={this.onHeaderPress.bind(this)}` should do the job for you.

Comment: @BilalBudhani I think we have no props/state inside the onHeaderPress therefore we don't need to bind this. But I also tried that it does not work, not sure if it's a bug for the component.....

Answer (score 3):

This is a binding issue. When you pass your `renderHeader` function to the `ListView` component, it will be called from the scope of the `ListView`, and not from that of your component anymore, thus losing the required reference to `onHeaderPress`. You need to `bind` your function like this:

```
render () {
    return (
      <ListView 
        style={styles.container}
        renderHeader={this.renderHeader.bind(this)}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(item) => this.renderListItem(item)}
        />
    );
  }
```

This is a very nasty bug because it silently fails. Accessing an undefined key in an object will simply return `undefined`, and the `onPress` prop is fine with that, it will not attempt calling the function, and you will not get an error message, thus making it difficult to track.

Comment: This solved my (very frustrating) issue perfectly—thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
renderHeader() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.header}
        onPress={this.renderHeader}
        activeOpacity={0.6}
        underlayColor={'blue'}>
        <View>
          <Text>
            Click here
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

Change to this.renderHeader should work.